# how to extract digits from a float in python

Tags: python

I have a floating point variable i.e.

```
123.456
```

how can I extract 12 ?

Comment: Is that the left-most 2 characters or is that the 10's and 100's place numerically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you render the float as a string, then you can just index the digits you like:

```
str(123.456)[:2]
```

"proof" in shell:

```
>>> str(123.456)[:2]
'12'
>>>
```

Comment: thanks. int(str(123.456)[:2] is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it a "mathy" way, you could also divide by 1e<number of digits to strip>. For example:

```
>>> int(123.456 / 1e1) # 1e1 == 10
12
>>> int(123.456 / 1e2) # 1e2 == 100
1
>>> int(123.456 / 1e-1) # 1e-1 == 0.1
1234
```

This will be much faster than converting float -> string -> int, but will not always behave exactly the same way as the string method above (eg, `int(1.2 / 1e1)` will be `0`, not `'1.'`).

Answer (score 2):

- result as float:

```py
123.456//10
# res: 12.0
```

- result as integer

```py
int(123.456)//10
# res: 12
```

- res as string: you have to care about the **position** of `.` !

```py
str(123.456)[:2]  
# res: "12"
```